# Is the problem of determining whether a CFG generates a string in the form 0*1* decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-free, formal-grammars

Given a grammar $G$, is it decidable whether $G$ generates any string in the form $0^*1^*$? Why?

I think it's undecidable but can't find any undecidable problem to reduce it to.

Comment: This is not really a research-level question and would be a better fit at cs.se. Here's a hint, however: The intersection of a context-free and a regular language is context-free, and emptiness of a context-free language is decidable. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @KlausDraeger Ah, I'm sorry - I confused CS.se with cstheory. Also thanks for the hint, I think I got it now.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4134695/5376789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is decidable.
We can construct a **total** Turing machine M that on input $G$ (where G is a CFG) checks whether it generates at least one string in $0^*1^*$.
Let $G_1$ be a regular language such that $L(G_1)=0^*1^*$.
Note that the intersection of CFL and a regular language is indeed a CFL. And hence a CFG for the intersection of $G$ and $G_1$ can be constructed. Call the constructed CFG $G'$. Also, the emptiness problem for CFG is decidable and hence just check the emptiness of the constructed CFG $G'$.
If it's empty, G doesn't generate any string in $0^*1^*$; and likewise if it's  not empty.